# <td style="width:"> Is Not Applying To Internet Explorer 7 And Internet Explorer 5

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have tables on some of my web pages. One part of the table has a style in the title above. On all web browsers except Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 5, the width above is correct. Whereas, on Internet Explorer 7 and 5 the width is wrong. It is too big.

Thanks,

William

Code for the whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta name="description" content="<#location> weather data"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Cumulus, <#location> weather data, weather, data, weather station"/>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300"/>
<title><#location></title>
<link href="weatherstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>


<body>
<div id="content">
<h1><#location></h1>
<h2 style="text-align: left; text-transform: none;"> Latitude:&nbsp;50.70189285&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Longitude:&nbsp;-3.30849957&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Elevation&nbsp;<#altitude></h2>
<!--[if IE]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_temp">Temperature/Humidity</td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Temperature</td>
  <td align="center"><#tempTH><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TtempTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Temperature</td>
  <td align="center"><#tempTL><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TtempTL></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Heat&nbsp;Index</td>
  <td align="center"><#heatindexTH><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TheatindexTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Wind&nbsp;Chill</td>
  <td align="center"><#wchillTL><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TwchillTL></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Apparent&nbsp;Temperature</td>
  <td align="center"><#apptempTH><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TapptempTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Apparent&nbsp;Temperature</td>
  <td align="center"><#apptempTL><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TapptempTL></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Dew&nbsp;Point</td>
  <td align="center"><#dewpointTH><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TdewpointTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Dew&nbsp;Point</td>
  <td align="center"><#dewpointTL><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TdewpointTL></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Temperature&nbsp;Range</td>
  <td align="center"><#temprange><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Humidity</td>
  <td align="center"><#humTH>%</td>
  <td align="right"><#ThumTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Humidity</td>
  <td align="center"><#humTL>%</td>
  <td align="right"><#ThumTL></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_wind">Wind</td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_wind_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Wind&nbsp;Gust</td>
  <td align="center"><#wgustTM>&nbsp;<#windunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TwgustTM></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_wind_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Average&nbsp;Wind&nbsp;Speed</td>
  <td align="center"><#windTM>&nbsp;<#windunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TwindTM></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_wind_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Dominant&nbsp;Direction</td>
  <td align="center"><#domwindbearing>&deg;&nbsp;<#domwinddir></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_wind_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Wind&nbsp;Run</td>
  <td align="center"><#windrun>&nbsp;<#windrununit></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_rainfall">Rainfall</td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Rainfall&nbsp;Rate</td>
  <td align="center"><#rrateTM>&nbsp;<#rainunit>/hr</td>
  <td align="right"><#TrrateTM></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Hourly&nbsp;Rainfall</td>
  <td align="center"><#hourlyrainTH>&nbsp;<#rainunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#ThourlyrainTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Rainfall&nbsp;Today</td>
  <td align="center"><#rfall>&nbsp;<#rainunit></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Days&nbsp;Since&nbsp;Last&nbsp;Dry&nbsp;Day</td>
  <td align="center"><#ConsecutiveRainDays></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Days&nbsp;Since&nbsp;It&nbsp;Last&nbsp;Rained</td>
  <td align="center"><#ConsecutiveDryDays></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_pressure">Pressure</td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_pressure_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Pressure</td>
  <td align="center"><#pressTH>&nbsp;<#pressunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TpressTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_pressure_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Pressure</td>
  <td align="center"><#pressTL>&nbsp;<#pressunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TpressTL></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" class="td_navigation_bar">:<a href="index.htm">Index</a>::<a href="today.htm">Today</a>::<a href="yesterday.htm">Yesterday</a>::<a href="thismonth.htm">This&nbsp;Month</a>::<a href="monthlyrecords.htm">Monthly Records</a>::<a href="thisyear.htm">This&nbsp;Year</a>::<a href="alltimerecords.htm">All Time Records</a>::<a href="trends.htm">Trends</a>:</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_temp">Temperature/Humidity</td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Temperature</td>
  <td align="center"><#tempTH><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TtempTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Temperature</td>
  <td align="center"><#tempTL><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TtempTL></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Heat&nbsp;Index</td>
  <td align="center"><#heatindexTH><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TheatindexTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Wind&nbsp;Chill</td>
  <td align="center"><#wchillTL><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TwchillTL></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Apparent&nbsp;Temperature</td>
  <td align="center"><#apptempTH><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TapptempTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Apparent&nbsp;Temperature</td>
  <td align="center"><#apptempTL><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TapptempTL></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Dew&nbsp;Point</td>
  <td align="center"><#dewpointTH><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TdewpointTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Dew&nbsp;Point</td>
  <td align="center"><#dewpointTL><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TdewpointTL></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Temperature&nbsp;Range</td>
  <td align="center"><#temprange><#tempunit></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Humidity</td>
  <td align="center"><#humTH>%</td>
  <td align="right"><#ThumTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_temperature_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Humidity</td>
  <td align="center"><#humTL>%</td>
  <td align="right"><#ThumTL></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_wind">Wind</td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_wind_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Wind&nbsp;Gust</td>
  <td align="center"><#wgustTM>&nbsp;<#windunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TwgustTM></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_wind_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Average&nbsp;Wind&nbsp;Speed</td>
  <td align="center"><#windTM>&nbsp;<#windunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TwindTM></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_wind_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Dominant&nbsp;Direction</td>
  <td align="center"><#domwindbearing>&deg;&nbsp;<#domwinddir></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_wind_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Wind&nbsp;Run</td>
  <td align="center"><#windrun>&nbsp;<#windrununit></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_rainfall">Rainfall</td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Rainfall&nbsp;Rate</td>
  <td align="center"><#rrateTM>&nbsp;<#rainunit>/hr</td>
  <td align="right"><#TrrateTM></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Hourly&nbsp;Rainfall</td>
  <td align="center"><#hourlyrainTH>&nbsp;<#rainunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#ThourlyrainTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Rainfall&nbsp;Today</td>
  <td align="center"><#rfall>&nbsp;<#rainunit></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Days&nbsp;Since&nbsp;Last&nbsp;Dry&nbsp;Day</td>
  <td align="center"><#ConsecutiveRainDays></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_rainfall_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Days&nbsp;Since&nbsp;It&nbsp;Last&nbsp;Rained</td>
  <td align="center"><#ConsecutiveDryDays></td>
  <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_pressure">Pressure</td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_pressure_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">High&nbsp;Pressure</td>
  <td align="center"><#pressTH>&nbsp;<#pressunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TpressTH></td>
</tr>
<tr class="td_pressure_data">
  <td class="main_table_text_labels" style="width: 199px">Low&nbsp;Pressure</td>
  <td align="center"><#pressTL>&nbsp;<#pressunit></td>
  <td align="right"><#TpressTL></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" class="td_navigation_bar">:<a href="index.htm">Index</a>::<a href="today.htm">Today</a>::<a href="yesterday.htm">Yesterday</a>::<a href="thismonth.htm">This&nbsp;Month</a>::<a href="monthlyrecords.htm">Monthly Records</a>::<a href="thisyear.htm">This&nbsp;Year</a>::<a href="alltimerecords.htm">All Time Records</a>::<a href="trends.htm">Trends</a>:</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<![endif]-->
<p class="credits"><br />
Page updated <#update format="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"><br/>
Powered by <a href="http://sandaysoft.com/products/cumulus">Cumulus</a> v<#version>       (<#build>)
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
    body {
background-color: white;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10pt;
color: black;
text-align: left;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left bottom;
    table-layout: fixed;
    }
    #content {
margin-top: 5%;
margin-right: 20%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
margin-left: 20%;
    width: 800px;
    }
    h1 {
font-size: 150%;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
padding-bottom: 1em;
text-align: center;
    }
    h2 {
font-size: 10pt;
color: black;
font-family: Arial;
text-align: left;
    }
    a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: underline;
font-weight: normal;
    }
    a:visited {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #000000;
    }
    a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #000000;
    }
    a:active {
text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000000;
    }
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-family: Arial;
    }
    .credits {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 100%;
text-align: left;
    }
    h3 {
font-size: 110%;
font-weight: normal;
color: #585858;
letter-spacing: 0.4em;
text-transform: lowercase;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: left;
    }
    ul {
font-size: 75%;
padding-bottom: 1em;
padding-top: 1em;
margin-left: 10%;
list-style-type: square;
text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    li {
padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
    h2 {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
color: black;
padding-bottom: .2em;
background-color: white;
text-align: left;
padding-top: .2em;
padding-right: 1em;
    }
    .blockquote {
background-color: #E7E7DE;
margin-right: 22%;
    }
    caption {
font-size: 100%;
font-style: normal;
padding-top: 0.5em;
padding-bottom: 0.25em;
text-align: center;
    }
    table {
font-family: Arial;
    }
    .tableseparator_temp {
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: 400;
background-color: #6699CC;
color: black;
padding: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .tableseparator_rainfall {

font-size: 100%;
font-weight: 400;
background-color: #6699CC;
color: black;
padding: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .tableseparator_wind {


font-size: 100%;
font-weight: 400;
background-color: #6699CC;
color: black;
padding: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .tableseparator_pressure {



font-size: 100%;
font-weight: 400;
background-color: #6699CC;
color: black;
padding: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    }
    td {
font-size: 100%;
padding-top: 0.2em;
padding-bottom: 0.2em;
color: black;
    }

    .td_thumbnails {
padding-top: 0.1em;
padding-right: 0.2em;
padding-bottom: 0.1em;
padding-left: 0.0em;
    }

    .td_temperature_data {
background-color: white;
    }
    .td_rainfall_data {

background-color: white;
    }
    .td_wind_data {


background-color: white;
    }
    .td_pressure_data {



background-color: white;
    }
    .td_navigation_bar {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .labels {
background-position: left;
    }
    .site_data {
text-align: right;
    }
    .colon_separator {
font-weight: 400;
background-position: left;
    }
```

Comment: Forget IE5. IE7 is more important. LOL :D

Comment: Why are you coding for browsers that has no support from Microsoft?

Comment: I'm not bothering now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the depreciated attribute rather than the CSS property and it will work.

```
td width=""
```

Comment: I tried it anyway and it doesn't work. Nothing will work with IE7 and IE5 seen as they are no unsupported so no code will change anything IE7 and IE5 display.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem but a couple other things you may want to look into are adding body { table-layout: fixed; }, or using <th>.  If you want to provide a screenshot and/or CSS I'll take a look.

Comment: Using table-layout: fixed; didn't work either. I have 7 pages using <td> tags. So, I don't want to have to re-code everything. The CSS for my website is now in my post.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to have a seperate CSS page and an IF statement at the top of the HTML that evaluates which web browser it is. Then, choose a different style sheet if it is IE 5 or 7

```
<!--[if IE]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_temp">Temperature/Humidity</td>......
</tbody>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

then we add the condition for if not right under that

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="tableseparator_temp">Temperature/Humidity</td>.........
</tbody>
</table
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Also, if you dont want to make a whole CSS page, you could put this if statement where the td occures and have 2 different tables based on where or not it is IE

Comment: Ok thanks. Would I use this? meta http-equiv= x-ua-compatible content= ie=7

Comment: see the changes above

Comment: alternatively, you could outline all styles in a style sheet. Then use this conditional logic where the CSS is attached and say IF IE grab this sheet.

Comment: Sorry get rid of the 7 my mistake [if IE]

Comment: you may need to tweak that to suit you as well. The IF could just go around the that 1 <td> OR you could also do the inverse [if !IE] if not equal to IE

Comment: I'm not sure and can't paste my whole page codes on here as they are too long.

Comment: Also, on IE8 and below there are now 2 tables.

Comment: [if gte IE 5] this means greater than or equal to IE 5 do this or just do the inverse if not IE

Comment: Nope, [if gte IE 5] doesn't work either. The center td does not move to where I want it even when I take out the additional width.

Comment: it works on my side... you have it exactly as I have it? put the second if right after the first?

Comment: Oh, hang on. I've got the table. But, still a bad layout.

Comment: I just copied and pasted it into an HTML file I had laying around and it worked for me... what browsers have you tried?

Comment: Anything above IE8 and GC will not show the table. Please can you edit your answer to show this HTML you have?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code you provided in your edit and it works

Comment: Strange. No workie in mine. I've posted my whole page to see if there is a problem somewhere else.

Comment: No, sorry. IE9 and IE10 do not display anything and GC. But, IE8, IE7 and IE5 do. Plus, the tables that are shown are still not correct. Is there really any point?

Comment: if was only IE 5 and 7 that did not work in the original code I would revert. This has always worked for me in the past... I don't know why it isnt now. Since IE8 is the lowest supported, I would drop support for IE 7 and under.

Comment: Sorry for all the running around just to end up where you started. I dont understand why that doesnt work...

Comment: Oh how stupid am I? I was saving the website file to my desktop not to my website!

Comment: Hmmm, kind of. Still got no table in IE10, Edge and GC. However, before adding in the <!--[if !IE]> there was a table on all of them. But, this made the text very big.

Comment: may be best to keep it how it was :( Chrome is much more important

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a stupid web browser after all that only 1% of the world use anyway.